# Create multiple URL shortcuts from a text file using a batch script

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, url

**Summary:** I have a set of reports I must to run, and would like to create links to each report online. The problem I'm having is how to make a batch file which can successfully loop through the file containing my URLs, and make an internet shortcut for each URL with a name based on data from URL itself.

Example URL exactly as shown, each URL is a line in a text file, (one report per day of the year):

```
<https://app.gomotive.com/en-US/#/reports/ifta-distance/vehicle;start_date=2023-01-01;end_date=2023-01-31;vehicle_ids=1103007;report_id=25;report_type=normal>
<https://app.gomotive.com/en-US/#/reports/ifta-distance/vehicle;start_date=2023-01-02;end_date=2023-01-31;vehicle_ids=1103007;report_id=25;report_type=normal>
<https://app.gomotive.com/en-US/#/reports/ifta-distance/vehicle;start_date=2023-01-03;end_date=2023-01-31;vehicle_ids=1103007;report_id=25;report_type=normal>
```

Breaking the URL down to understand the static vs dynamic data and how to manipulate it.

- `https://app.gomotive.com/en-US/#/reports/ifta-distance/vehicle;start_date=` (static data)
- `2023-01-01` (dynamic data - format YYYY-mm-DD)
- `;end_date=` (static data)
- `2023-01-31` (dynamic data - format YYYY-mm-DD)
- `;vehicle_ids=1103007;report_id=25;report_type=normal` (static data)

I'm trying to make the URL shortcut names based off the line itself for example, with the URL `https://app.gomotive.com/en-US/#/reports/ifta-distance/vehicle;start_date=2023-01-01;end_date=2023-01-31;vehicle_ids=1103007;report_id=25;report_type=normal`, I'd like to create a shortcut in directory named: `C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Folder for the links\01-01-2023 mileage report.URL`. The filename of 01-01-2023 being dynamic based on the date stated in the URL itself.
Also I found out the hard way, the other day, this computer `"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Anywhere Else"` is not a valid directory, not sure if this is a new Windows 11 trait, (moved from Win 7), or a OneDrive issue. Either way, any old code I had that used the `%UserProfile%` variable is needing re-done, or I need to make a new environment variable.

Here are my issue(s):

1. - I have no experience using for looping command, let alone the restrictions of batch when using special characters. I thought I'd best ask before goofing something up terribly (special characters in the text file containing all the URLS).
2. - The URL can vary on length ,so I'm not sure how to extract the month/day/year to use in the filename correctly.
3. - Batch is the only language I have any experience with, and that is limited too. So whilst I'm sure there are much better options to do the task I'm wanting, I don't know them, to try them.

What I have done:

I used spreadsheet to break the URL down, modify the dates for the entire year, concatenate the data in a manner which made a proper working URL for each day of the year, added a column for the filename, and `Echo @Echo Off> To the filename`, `Echo Start (the URL)>> To the filename`, `Echo Exit>> To the filename`.
At which point, I was able to copy the crude columns of code from the spreadsheet, and paste them into the Command Prompt, which created a batch file for each URL, (file name was based on date) like so:

```bash
@Echo OFF
Start "" "https://app.gomotive.com/en-US/#/reports/ifta-distance/vehicle;start_date=2023-01-
01;end_date=2023-01-31;vehicle_ids=1103007;report_id=25;report_type=normal"
Exit
```

Making a working batch file for each link but surely not the right way to do it. *(It's not the first time I've used a spreadsheet to break apart a directory or URL and re-constitute it for a batch file)*.

However I feel making actual internet shortcuts would be a much better way to do this across all forms of devices, (I think one of the people who may look at the reports from time to time use MacOS, and I'm assuming a batch file to "start" the URL won't work on their Mac, let alone not being the most friendly way of doing the job.

What my mind is telling me so far to do, (this is the batch file in my mind at the moment):

```bash
@Echo Off
CLS
REM Batch file create URLs based on text file
REM Filenames based on URL data from line in file
REM File containing URLs C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation\FileNameOfURLS.txt
REM Save directory C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation\All URLS Here
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation\FileNameOfURLS.txt)      
do (Echo [InternetShortcut] > "C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation\%Option1%.URL" 
echo URL=%%A >> "C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation\%Option1%.URL" 
echo IconFile=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe >>     
"C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation\%Option1%.URL"
echo IconIndex=0 >> "C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation\%Option1%.URL"
)
Exit
```

But I'm lost on how to extract the mm-DD-YYYY from the URL in the text file, and set it as the "option1", as I feel there is need for a second `for` command somewhere, to make this possible.

I have not ran my potential code, as shown above, through this system yet as I'm not sure how to make the filenames based on the data in the URL of the file `filenames.txt`, and I'm not sure this is even possible.

I did break the URLs down (365x) in spreadsheet, re-constitute them with proper dates, and make a column for filenames based on those dates, where I was able to further concatenate lines like `Echo @Echo Off>FileName(s).bat`, `Echo Start "" "The URL with updated dates">>FileName(s).bat` and `Echo Exit>>FileName(s).bat`, effectively creating a crude batch file containing the proper link, and having a correct name based on the date of the URL via the Command Prompt. However, making 365 batch files per year, and being locked to only Windows OS, not able to run those batch files on my phone either, makes them half as useful as if they were a `.url` file which any device can open.

Comment: That code is not valid. The `do` must be immediately preceded by the closing parenthesis, or for readability, the closing parenthesis and a space. You have got it preceded by a carriage return and line feed pair. And please do not treat us like children, we do not struggle to read, and do not wish to try to do it with everything in Title Case. Please rewrite your post without such nonesense.

Comment: I Was By No Means Treating ANYONE Like Children, Its My Thought Process, And As I Mentioned In Post I've NO Experience With FOR Commands Or Such So That's New To Me, I Guess I'm The One That Needs To Be Treated Like A Child As I'm TRYING To Learn How These Things Work To Make Some Of My Tasks Easier But I'll Try To Make The Edit You Mentioned. On A Side Note, I WRITE And Type The Same Manner Caps The First Of Most Every Word As It's Easier For Me To See, Read And Understand It That Way, I Won't Be Changing That Sorry!

Comment: How about you redirect your thinking to the positives of my comment instead. I told you there was a problem with your code, and what it was. Instead of acknowledging it, or even fixing it quietly, you decided to have a rant. Did you come here looking for help? for an argument? or to be ignored?

Comment: I have changed your question into a more redable form as a courtesy to you. Please note, the question is not for you to read, it is for others. You should also not expect everyone else to use All Capitals and Title Case in their responses to you. Anyhow, at present your post requires focus. We expect you to ask a single specific question about a reproducible programming problem, not ask for us to read a huge question containing unnecessary bloat, and seemingly looking for help with a complete programming task. Tell us which specific part of your code is giving you a problem, and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would think, based upon your provided text file content, and your unattempted code, it could be done:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "URLFile=C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation\FileNameOfURLS.txt"
Set "SaveDir=C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Report Creation"

For /F "UseBackQ Delims=<>" %%G In ("%URLFile%") Do (
    For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=;=" %%H In ("%%~G") Do (
        Echo [InternetShortcut]
        Echo URL="%%~G"
        Echo IconFile="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
        Echo IconIndex=0
    ) 1>"%SaveDir%\%%H.url"
)
```

As you had assumed, an additional `for` loop was needed.

---

*Please be aware however, that it is not very likely that your phone, or a Mac will have a copy of chrome.exe in the location stipulated in the `IconFile` entry. So you may be better advised to miss out those two `Icon*` keys, or at least their values.*

Comment: just a few seconds before I was ready to send my answer, but you forgot to rearrange the date to the desired format (can be done with a third `for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%X in ("%%H") do ...` and `1>"%SaveDir%\%%Z-%%Y-%%X.url"`)

Comment: TBF @Stephan, I didn't do it because it isn't necessary. The URL already has the date in a sortable order, i.e. `YYYY-mm-DD`, which IMO is better for the end user.

Comment: agreed, I also prefer a sortable format. But the shortcut file name is intended for "human use", so the changed format *might* be a requirement (not everyone is used to ISO-derived date formats).

Comment: I'm Going To Do Some Testing With That And Try To Learn A Little More About How Its Working, As I Stated I'm Learning A Little At A Time, Thank You So Much For Giving Me Some Guidance, I Can't Say I've Ever Seen A Nested For Command In Batch.

Comment: Granted @Stephan, but imagine having a directory with a minimum of 365 individual URLs on a mobile OS, a Windows OS and MacOS. Then imagine trying to visit a specific URL quickly based upon its date. Which format would be the simplest way to do that? TBF, IMO, the best way would be to create a HTML file containing each URL with Monthly Sections, a tabular or calendar like format. One file compatible on any browser, in any OS, whereby the end user can quickly visit the required URL in a user friendly way.

Comment: @Compo: you don't have to convince *me* - I'm on the same page. But out of experience: some people think, the preferred date format should be `DD-MM-YYYY` (or even `D-M-YYYY`). I stopped years ago trying to make them rethink.

Comment: @Compo Yes, For My Use The MM/DD/YYYY Format Makes Finding Things Easier And Is The Standard I Personally Use And Tends To Be The Most Common Among My Co-Workers, Friends, Etc. So If Someone Needed To Take A Glance At Something And Verify Information It Makes It Much Quicker Looking For The Right MM Then The Right DD, These "Reports" Are 365 Per YEAR PER TRUCK, So I Re-Code Them To Match The Right Date Values For The Year And Truck Number In Spreadsheet, Copy The Column Of New "Homemade" URLS And Run Them Into The URL Text File Then Through The Batch To Make Links, And Sort Links Manually

Comment: In Total I'll Be Having Folders For Each Truck, Then Each YEAR, Then The Links Sorted By Months Much Like...
Desktop\Reports\Truck 123
Desktop\Reports\Truck 456
(Around 10 Trucks)

\Desktop\Reports\Truck 123\2022\01 - January
\Desktop\Reports\Truck 123\2022\02 - Feburary
ETC, ETC,. And

\Desktop\Reports\Truck 123\2023\01 - January
\Desktop\Reports\Truck 123\2023\02 - Feburary
Etc, Etc. 

So Navigating The File System Helps Take Alot Of The Hassle Out But There Are Still Many Links. Unfortunately The Online Portal Could Solve This IF They Broke Reports By Date, Which They Dont.

Comment: Well use the advice in Stephan's comment to implement that change. To put it in your own terms, "I Won't Be Changing That Sorry!".

Comment: @Compo I Am Certainly Going To Work With That Suggestion And Also Seeing If I Cant Work Into The Whole File An Integrated Directory Creation Where It Can Place Specific Files Into Folders Automatically. I Wanted To Thank You For Helping Sort This Out, I Didn't Even Know Nested IF Commands Were Possible Although I Assumed So I Have A LOT To Learn On That Subject Yet. Right Now I'm Trying To Further Research The Function And Exactly How It Operates And Its Parameters So I Can Utilize It And Learn From Experience, But Thank You For Taking The Time To Help With A Solution!